# Make element x pixels wider than its liquid width container?

Tags: css

I have a container that has a liquid width and 20px of padding. I want most contained elements to respect the padding. However a few elements I want to ignore the padding and be the same width as the container itself. Is this possible with CSS?

I know that I could apply margins to the contained elements instead, however, due to the complexity of my actual html this isn't ideal.

```html
<div class="cont">
    <div class="item-normal">Normal Item</div>
    <div class="item-wide">wide Item</div>
    <div class="item-normal">Normal Item</div>
    <div class="item-wide">wide Item</div>
    <div class="item-normal">Normal Item</div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.cont {
    background: grey;
    padding: 20px;  
}
.item-normal {
    background: blue;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.item-wide {
    margin-left: -20px;
    background: gold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `margin-right:-20px;` to `.item-wide`:

```
.item-wide {
    margin-left: -20px;
    background: gold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right:-20px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yqZ9M/)**

You can also combine the three separate margins in that rule to just `margin: 0 -20px 10px;`

Answer (score 2):

Just add `margin-right: -20px` as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebheP/